# How to calculate x, y, z, m in Postgis

Tags: postgis-2.0, st-geometry

Somebody know how can I calculate the **x,y,z,m** parameters from a **MultiLineStringZM** in Postgis?

I would like to know **x,y,z** and **m** from the points what are made the polyline.

When I try calculate it by this way "*st_x,st_y, st_z, st_m*" postgis go up an error message:
ERROR:  Argument to M() must be a point

Any idea?

Thanks,

JM

Comment: Your problem is, that st_x() works with a single point. Your current geometry object is a MultiLineStringZM. What is the 'idea', 'target' of using the function..., please elaborate.

Comment: I would like to know what are the x,y,z,m coordinates of each point that is compositing each polyline. But I don´t know how can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html

The rest should be straight forward (ST_X, etc).

I hope it works out for you!